# Facebook SDK 3.0 auth dialog (only once?)

Tags: android, facebook

I refer to the sample SessionLoginSample and set some other permissions. In my Android phone, there is a Facebook app(apk).
I hit the login button, then Auth dialog is popped.

I hit the "Cancel". And I got the error "com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException: The user denied the app".

After that, I hit login button, but the Auth dialog could not appear.
Could someone help to tell me how to get the Auth dialog again?